# Can't select availability set when creating a backend pool

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-load-balancer, azure-availability-set

When I try to create a backend pool in the azure portal, I don't get prompted for an availability set; I just see a drop-down list of virtual networks but the list is empty.

When I first tried this I didn't know about availability sets. I have now created an availability set but I still don't get any option to select an availability set either when creating a backend pool or when creating a new VM.

I have seen tutorials and videos on setting up load balancing on azure, but on my azure portal I just don't see the same options they have in the screenshots.

Are availability sets still relevant or are they now deprecated? if they are still in use, is there anything I need to do to enable them?

Comment: are you using standard load balancer? either was, availability sets are the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Availability Sets are not deprecated.
If you create an Availability Set in the same Resource Group with the Load Balancer you must be able to see it.
And one more thing, when you must select the Availability Set while you create a Virtual Machine you cannot add it if the virtual machine already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, after looking more closely I realized that in the 3rd step for creating the VM, the screen wasn't loading completely. As well as the Availability Set selection being completely blank, a couple of the other drop-down boxes just said "loading..." next to them so basically I couldn't create a VM at all.

I tried waiting for a while, logging out and back in etc but it made no difference. I tried on a different Azure subscription and everything worked as expected. The original subscription used to work, so I suspect my Availability set had somehow not been created properly and this was causing the screen to bork.

I deleted the Availability set and created another one with all the same parameters, and now it seems to be working properly.

Comment: Also it seems that if you must have the availability set in existence before you create the load balancer. if you create a load balancer then the availability set, you have to delete the load balancer and recreate it before it will detect the availability set